# How to instantiate a generic class

Tags: java

I thought I understood how to use `.class` and `Class<>` but I guess not.  The below `super(ApprovalWorkstation.class` is not being mapped to the constructor.  How can I be sure that I'm passing a class reference so that the base `WorkstationRequest` can instantiate it?

```
public class ApprovalWorkstation extends Workstation {

    public ApprovalWorkstation(WorkstationEntity entity) {
        super(entity);
    }
}

public class WorkstationRequest extends com.production.socket.request.WorkstationRequest {
    public WorkstationRequest() {
        super(ApprovalWorkstation.class); //unable to map to constructor
    }
}
```

This is the base `WorkstationRequest` that's extended above

```
public class WorkstationRequest {
    private Class<Workstation> workstationClass;

    public void WorkstationRequest(Class<Workstation> workstationClass) {
        this.workstationClass = workstationClass;
    }
```

**update**

I'm sorry for the confusion, my constructor actually has `Class<Workstation>` and not `Workstation` as I initially had.

Comment: `Workstation` and `Class<Workstation>` are no the same.  It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: the last piece of code is wrong, you can't assign `Workstation` instance to `Class<Workstation>` variable.

Comment: Could you not pass in an object and get the class from that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be able to pass both `Workstation` class and it's child classes you should change definition of `WorkstationRequest` to the following:

```
public class WorkstationRequest {
    private Class<? extends Workstation> workstationClass;

    public WorkstationRequest(Class<? extends Workstation> workstationClass) {
        this.workstationClass = workstationClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: While I needed `? extends`, I also had a return value of `void` which meant it wasn't a constructor

Comment: oops, copy paste rocks. fixed

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign an instance of `Worstation` to field of type `Class<Workstation>` which is obviously not the same.

What you're probably trying to do is:

```
public WorkstationRequest(Class<Workstation> workstationClass) {
```

Of course there is no return type (`void`) in constructors. Your "constructor" is simply a method:

```
public void WorkstationRequest(Class<Workstation> workstationClass) { // method
public      WorkstationRequest(Class<Workstation> workstationClass) { // constructor
```

Comment: shoot, I'm sorry... `Class<Workstation>` is what I have.  I was toying around with other things trying to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but you are passing in a `Workstation` instance while what needed is a `Class<Workstation>`. Maybe use `workstationClass.getClass()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no constructor that takes a `Class` as a parameter in the base WorkstationRequest class.
2. Constructors do NOT have a return type, so `public void WorkstationRequest` needs to be changed to `public WorkstationRequest`.